# Errors were encountered while processing: /var/cache/apt/archives/cups-daemon_2.1.3-4ubuntu0.11_arm64.deb

Tags: 16.04, apt, dpkg, dependencies

I am not able to apt-get upgrade, I get this error. Tried multiple solutions but nothing worked. I tried to install 'cups-daemon' package and again I get below copied error. How do I resolve this?

```
root@ubuntu:~# apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 cups : Depends: cups-daemon (>= 2.1.3-4ubuntu0.11) but 2.1.3-4ubuntu0.7 is installed
 cups-core-drivers : Depends: cups-daemon (>= 2.1.3-4ubuntu0.11) but 2.1.3-4ubuntu0.7 is installed
 cups-daemon : Depends: libcups2 (= 2.1.3-4ubuntu0.7) but 2.1.3-4ubuntu0.11 is installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
```

```
root@ubuntu:~# apt-get -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libavc1394-0 libcaca0 libcdparanoia0 libdv4 libgstreamer-plugins-good1.0-0
  libiec61883-0 libopus0 libraw1394-11 libshout3 libspeex1 libtag1v5
  libtag1v5-vanilla libtheora0 libvisual-0.4-0 libwavpack1
Use 'apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  cups-daemon
Suggested packages:
  cups-bsd foomatic-db-compressed-ppds | foomatic-db printer-driver-hpcups
  hplip cups-pdf smbclient
The following packages will be upgraded:
  cups-daemon
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 151 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/275 kB of archives.
After this operation, 4096 B disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'cloud-guest-utils' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'cloud-initramfs-copymods' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'cloud-initramfs-dyn-netconf' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
(Reading database ... 83039 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../cups-daemon_2.1.3-4ubuntu0.11_arm64.deb ...
Failed to stop cups.path: Unit cups.path not loaded.
dpkg: warning: subprocess old pre-removal script returned error exit status 5
dpkg: trying script from the new package instead ...
Failed to stop cups.socket: Unit cups.socket not loaded.
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/cups-daemon_2.1.3-4ubuntu0.11_arm64.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess new pre-removal script returned error exit status 5
/usr/bin/deb-systemd-helper: error: unable to read cups.path
/usr/bin/deb-systemd-helper: error: unable to read cups.service
/usr/bin/deb-systemd-helper: error: unable to read cups.socket
Failed to get unit file state for cups.path: No such file or directory
cups.path is a disabled or a static unit, not starting it.
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/cups-daemon_2.1.3-4ubuntu0.11_arm64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

```
prsn@ubuntu:/home$ sudo apt install cups-daemon
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libavc1394-0 libcaca0 libcdparanoia0 libdv4 libgstreamer-plugins-good1.0-0
  libiec61883-0 libopus0 libraw1394-11 libshout3 libspeex1 libtag1v5
  libtag1v5-vanilla libtheora0 libvisual-0.4-0 libwavpack1
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
Suggested packages:
  cups-bsd foomatic-db-compressed-ppds | foomatic-db printer-driver-hpcups
  hplip cups-pdf smbclient
The following packages will be upgraded:
  cups-daemon
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 151 not upgraded.
85 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/275 kB of archives.
After this operation, 4096 B disk space will be freed.
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'cloud-guest-utils' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'cloud-initramfs-copymods' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'cloud-initramfs-dyn-netconf' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
(Reading database ... 83039 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../cups-daemon_2.1.3-4ubuntu0.11_arm64.deb ...
Failed to stop cups.path: Unit cups.path not loaded.
dpkg: warning: subprocess old pre-removal script returned error exit status 5
dpkg: trying script from the new package instead ...
Failed to stop cups.socket: Unit cups.socket not loaded.
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/cups-daemon_2.1.3-4ubuntu0.11_arm64.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess new pre-removal script returned error exit status 5
/usr/bin/deb-systemd-helper: error: unable to read cups.path
/usr/bin/deb-systemd-helper: error: unable to read cups.service
/usr/bin/deb-systemd-helper: error: unable to read cups.socket
Failed to get unit file state for cups.path: No such file or directory
cups.path is a disabled or a static unit, not starting it.
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/cups-daemon_2.1.3-4ubuntu0.11_arm64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Did you remember to run `sudo apt update` before other `apt` commands?  Why are you root? Before this, how often are you updating your system?

Comment: Yes, I ran apt update first and it didn't give any error. I have booted ubuntu on Xilinx ZynqMP board and  trying to update the system for the first time.

Comment: There should not be file lists missing from a new install. That's an unusually high number of errors for a new install. Your workflow or your storage seem suspect.

Comment: @user535733 I am booting OS on the xilinx board, I got the rootfs from xilinx website. So when I tried to install any packages on this OS, I get cups-daemon error. I tried install cups-daemon as well but still it did not works. How to get rid of this?